# how to extract the data from page in Json form?

Tags: python, json, pandas, web-scraping

hi I would like to web scrape an internet site [here](https://www.quantalys.com/espace/518)

From someone on stacker flow (thx to him), I get this solution:

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.quantalys.com/espace/518"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
data = soup.select_one("#chartEncours8a input")["value"]
data = json.loads(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data['dataProvider'])
df['unit'] = data['valueAxes'][0]['unit']
print(df)
```

I found where the data come from but do not understand the link between the code and the inspection of the Internet page [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiZqu.jpg). Maybe it is not here that the code found the data ???

where does `#chartEncours8a input")["value"]` come from ? I can not find them in the inspection ? I would like to reproduce this output so I need to understand.

how to extract data from a web site

Comment: As I stated in my answer, the values are found in **raw** HTML source: https://ibb.co/QP2S912

Comment: I can see the 'd-"chartEncours8a" but not 'chart8a input' (from your picture) ? and don't see data['dataProvider'] ? How from the site can I find the data - it is my question maybe reformulate in a simpler manner ?

Comment: `"#chartEncours8a input"` in my script is CSS selector. It means select `<input>` tag that is under a tag with `id="chartEncours8a"`. The data is encoded in `value=` attribute in Json format.

Comment: @Andrej, It means that in this case I always need to add input ? Where can I find information on this (website or book) ? Thx a lot !

Comment: css selectors are pretty straightforward. You can learn directly from [BeautifulSoup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors-through-the-css-property) or [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp). [Here are all css references](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp). You can play around with css selectors in dev-tools. To get selector of element in dev-tool you can do `Right Click`->`Copy`->`copy selector` and to find matches, do `Ctrl+F` and paste the selector

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup allows you to traverse the rendered html of the page as a tree, which is what `soup.select_one("#chartEncours8a input")["value"]`.

As the author of your previous answer stated, inspect element does not give you the info you are looking for. Examining the raw html (which BeautifulSoup) is reading can show you a link.

Comment: with just this code `import json`
`import requests`
`import pandas as pd`
`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

`url = "https://www.quantalys.com/espace/518"`

`soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")`  `print(soup)` ?